# Problem with if loop when trying send a few files

Tags: bash, loops, ftp

I need sending a few files to FTP server but the following script runs only one time, even if there are more entries in the document that have string "example". In /abc.txt I have paths to files which I want sending to FTP server.

```
#!/bin/sh

if grep -q example "/abc.txt" ; 
then
var=$( cat /abc.txt )
HOST='X.X.X.X'
USER='USER'
PASSWD='PASSWORD'
cd $var
FILE='./*.txt'

ftp -nv $HOST > /abc.log.txt <<ENDSCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
passive
put $FILE
bye
quit
ENDSCRIPT
echo $FILE
sed -i '1d' "/abc.txt"
else
    echo "error"
fi
```

Comment: The script seems to contain a number of false assumptions. It would help us answer if you explained the script's logic and what you expect or hope to happen. Code which doesn't do what you want is often a poor way to explain what you do want.

Comment: Since you don't have a single explicit loop in your script, how do you expect it to run more than once?

Comment: Of course :) thanks for help me I added while loop befor if condition

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `for`, and I think using `-q` option for grep here is unnecessary:

```
for var in $(grep  example ./abc.txt); do
       your_code_here
done
```

Here `var` will each time contain the name of the file.

Comment: This will have some robustness problems. [Don't read lines with `for`.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)